# Spring Boot dead lock with websphere liberty classloader

Tags: spring-cloud, websphere-liberty, spring-cloud-netflix

I am running spring boot applications on WebSphere Liberty servers(version 16.0.0.4).  There more than on war with springboot application run on single instance of liberty.  The spring library version we have are

1. Spring Core - 4.3.2.RELEASE
2. org.springframework.cloud - Brixton.SR5
3. org.springframework.boot - 1.4.0.RELEASE

Below are the stack trace for dead lock

Could you please help us understand what could be potential issue?

```
Owns Monitor Lock on com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ThreadContextClassLoader@0x00000000C8FAA768
Waiting for Monitor Lock on com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/AppClassLoader@0x00000000C4126BA8 
at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805(Compiled Code))
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:116(Compiled Code))
at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846(Compiled Code))
at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825(Compiled Code))
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass0(UnifiedClassLoader.java:108)
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader$Delegation.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:79)
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:103)
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ThreadContextClassLoader.loadClass(ThreadContextClassLoader.java:112)
at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805(Compiled Code))
at java/util/ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2666)
at java/util/ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1527(Compiled Code))
at java/util/ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1491(Compiled Code))
at java/util/ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1445(Compiled Code))
at java/util/ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1380(Compiled Code))
at java/util/ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1093)
at org/apache/bval/jsr/DefaultMessageInterpolator.loadBundle(DefaultMessageInterpolator.java:200)
at org/apache/bval/jsr/DefaultMessageInterpolator.getFileBasedResourceBundle(DefaultMessageInterpolator.java:177)
at org/apache/bval/jsr/DefaultMessageInterpolator.findUserResourceBundle(DefaultMessageInterpolator.java:283)
at org/apache/bval/jsr/DefaultMessageInterpolator.(DefaultMessageInterpolator.java:82)
at org/apache/bval/jsr/DefaultMessageInterpolator.(DefaultMessageInterpolator.java:69)
at org/apache/bval/jsr/ConfigurationImpl.(ConfigurationImpl.java:77)
at org/apache/bval/jsr/ApacheValidationProvider.createGenericConfiguration(ApacheValidationProvider.java:63)
at javax/validation/Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:164)
at org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/BackgroundPreinitializer$ValidationInitializer.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:107)
at org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/BackgroundPreinitializer$1.runSafely(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:59)
at org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/BackgroundPreinitializer$1.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:52)
at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:785)

------------------------------------------

Owns Monitor Lock on com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/AppClassLoader@0x00000000C4126BA8
Waiting for Monitor Lock on com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ThreadContextClassLoader@0x00000000C8FAA768 

at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:824(Compiled Code))
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass0(UnifiedClassLoader.java:108)
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader$Delegation.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:79)
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:103)
at com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/ThreadContextClassLoader.loadClass(ThreadContextClassLoader.java:112)
at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805(Compiled Code))
at org/apache/logging/log4j/util/LoaderUtil.loadClass(LoaderUtil.java:120)
at org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.createConverter(Log4jLogger.java:416)
at org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.(Log4jLogger.java:54)
at org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
at org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
at org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:48)
at org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
at org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
at org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
at org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
at org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
at org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/config/PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:63)
at java/lang/Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java/lang/Class.forName(Class.java:348(Compiled Code))
at org/springframework/cglib/core/ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:415)
at org/springframework/cglib/core/AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
at org/springframework/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
at org/springframework/cglib/core/AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
at org/springframework/cglib/core/AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
at org/springframework/cglib/core/internal/LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
at java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277(Compiled Code))
at org/springframework/cglib/core/internal/LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
at org/springframework/cglib/core/internal/LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
at org/springframework/cglib/core/AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
at org/springframework/cglib/core/AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
at org/springframework/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
at org/springframework/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337)
at org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:135)
at org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:107)
at org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:406)
at org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
at org/springframework/context/support/PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
at org/springframework/context/support/PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130)
at org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
at org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
at org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
at org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
at org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
at org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
at org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:140)
at org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
at org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
at org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
at org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
at org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
at org/springframework/boot/context/event/EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
at org/springframework/boot/SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:335)
at org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org/springframework/boot/web/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:150)
at org/springframework/boot/web/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:130)
at org/springframework/boot/web/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
at org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2523)
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1054)
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6562)
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/osgi/DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:468)
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/osgi/DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:463)
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/osgi/WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1004)
at com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/osgi/WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:825)
at com/ibm/ws/app/manager/module/internal/ModuleHandlerBase.deployModule(ModuleHandlerBase.java:100)
at com/ibm/ws/app/manager/module/internal/DeployedModuleInfoImpl.installModule(DeployedModuleInfoImpl.java:50)
at com/ibm/ws/app/manager/module/internal/DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:420)
at com/ibm/ws/app/manager/module/internal/DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:406)
at com/ibm/ws/app/manager/war/internal/WARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(WARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:66)
at com/ibm/ws/app/manager/internal/statemachine/StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:141)
at com/ibm/ws/app/manager/internal/statemachine/ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1191)
at com/ibm/ws/app/manager/internal/statemachine/ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:804)
at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153(Compiled Code))
at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

Comment: This appears to be the exact same question as this one you posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103280/multiple-war-in-single-liberty-profile.  Can you please close out one of them?  Otherwise we will probably randomly close one of them as a duplicate

Comment: Yes, I deleted it.

Comment: Do you have a javacore from the deadlock?  That'll provide a fuller picture of the JVM's state and let us know which version of Java is being run.  The way locking is handled for classloaders has changed between different J9 releases.

Answer (score 1):

The two stack traces are very useful info — thanks.

The first stack trace makes sense to me. The `ThreadContextClassLoader` is delegating to the `AppClassLoader`, and this is the correct order of operation and therefore the correct order in which the locks should be obtained.

The second stack trace leaves me somewhat confused. I cannot see any entries in that stack that are obviously holding the `AppClassLoader` monitor. I have conferred with a colleague, and the most likely scenario is that the `Class.forName()` is being passed the `AppClassLoader` and that the native `Class.forNameImpl()` method is holding the monitor for that loader. This only becomes a problem when the class being initialised (PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration) reaches out through apache logging to initialise another class, which apache logging loads using the loader obtained from the thread context.

If Springboot were to use the class loader from the thread context instead of the loader obtained from `Class.getClassLoader()` this might prevent this problem from happening. Springboot can't assume it is running in a container, but it could at least look for a thread context class loader first, before trying `Class.getClassLoader()`.

One possible way to avoid this deadlock would be to separate out the Springboot classes into their own library, and reference this as a common library from the application configuration. Take a look at steps 1–4 in [this Knowledge Center article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.express.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_shared_libs.html). This should mean that the second thread's stack locks the library class loader rather than the application class loader. This will not guarantee avoiding the deadlock because the ordering is still unexpected, but it might make it unlikely to occur (depending on what the first thread in this scenario is loading and why it coincides with the other thread).

Comment: Thanks, i will try and get back to you